# certificate verify failed on Windows using openssl

Tags: c, windows, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm new to using openssl. I'm following the tutorial on the openssl website but I can't make it work.

I'm on a clean Windows 10 64 bits install. I downloaded openssl.

I followed the tutorial here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client

However I cannot make it work and don't know how to debug it. Googling the error message didn't help.

<strike>I got the certificate chain using:
`echo -n | openssl s_client -connect www.random.org:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > random-org-chain.pem`</strike>

Edit: This was the wrong part. I now got the proper certificate for [www.random.org](http://www.random.org) using `certmgr.msc` thanks to @dave_thompson_085. Also it's not a certificate chain in this case but just the root certificate.

Here is the full source code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/opensslconf.h>
#include "C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include\openssl\applink.c"

#if (SSLEAY_VERSION_NUMBER >= 0x0907000L)
#include <openssl/conf.h>
#endif

#define HOST_NAME "www.random.org"
#define HOST_PORT "443"
#define HOST_RESOURCE "/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=32&format=h"

void init_openssl_library(void)
{
    (void)SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    // ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    // OPENSSL_config(NULL);
#if defined (OPENSSL_THREADS)
    fprintf(stdout, "Warning: thread locking is not implemented\n");
#endif
}

void handleFailure(const char *s)
{
    printf("failed at %s\n", s);
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);
}

int main()
{
    long res = 1;

    SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
    BIO *web = NULL, *out = NULL;
    SSL *ssl = NULL;

    init_openssl_library();

    const SSL_METHOD *method = SSLv23_method();
    if (method == NULL) handleFailure("method");

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (ctx == NULL) handleFailure("new ctx");

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);

    SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);

    const long flags
        = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
    SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);

    res = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "random-org-chain.pem", NULL);
    if (res != 1) handleFailure("verify locations");

    web = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    if (web == NULL) handleFailure("new ssl connect");

    res = BIO_set_conn_hostname(web, HOST_NAME ":" HOST_PORT);
    if (res != 1) handleFailure("set conn hostname");

    BIO_get_ssl(web, &ssl);
    if (ssl == NULL) handleFailure("get ssl");

    const char PREFERRED_CIPHERS[] = "HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!PSK:!SRP:!MD5:!RC4";
    res = SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, PREFERRED_CIPHERS);
    if (res != 1) handleFailure("set cipher list");

    res = SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, HOST_NAME);
    if (res != 1) handleFailure("set tlsext");

    out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
    if (out == NULL) handleFailure("new fp");

    res = BIO_do_connect(web);
    if (res != 1) handleFailure("connect");

    res = BIO_do_handshake(web);
    if (res != 1) handleFailure("handshake");

    X509 *cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
    if (cert) X509_free(cert);
    if (cert == NULL) handleFailure("get peer cert");

    res = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
    if (res != X509_V_OK) handleFailure("verify result");

    // TODO: hostname verification

    BIO_puts(
        web,
        "GET " HOST_RESOURCE " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: " HOST_NAME "\r\n"
        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"
    );
    BIO_puts(out, "\n");

    int len = 0;
    do
    {
        char buff[1536];
        len = BIO_read(web, buff, sizeof(buff));
        if (len > 0)
            BIO_write(out, buff, len);
    } while (len > 0 || BIO_should_retry(web));
    
    if (out) BIO_free(out);
    if (web != NULL) BIO_free_all(web);
    if (ctx != NULL) SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile this code with:

`gcc -x c -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror main.cpp -L'C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib' -lssl -lcrypto -I'C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include'`

And when I run it I get this ouput:

```
Warning: thread locking is not implemented
failed at connect
980F0000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl\statem\statem_clnt.c:1890:
failed at handshake
failed at get peer cert
failed at verify result
```

I believe there is an error with my certificate but I don't understand what it is. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the server certificate sent by www.random.org as a trusted CA certificate chain.

Comment: @IanAbbott I don't understand what it means. What can I do about it and where could I learn more about it?

Comment: Looks like it is actually failing at connect, and then you are continuing the code even though you received a wrong status word (?)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Yes I am. But this is just for testing, I know I should return when encountering an error. Only the failed at connect part is relevant.

Comment: There are other posts that go into this kind of failure. Usually it is not being able to connect to the socket, e.g. because of firewall rules. Obviously, if no connection is made then the handshake will fail, and if no cert chain is received then the followup calls will also fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @IanAbbott said, the file (or directory) provided to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` must include the *root CA* certificate (or as the wiki page more formally says, the trust anchor) that validates the cert of the server you want to connect to. It *may* include other chain cert(s) but does not need to, and in most cases where you communicate with more than one server it needs to contain more than one root, so we usually call this something like 'CA-list' or 'root-list' or 'root-CA-list', not '{specific-thing}-chain'.

The cert you got in your file using `openssl s_client ... >file` is only the *server* aka *end-entity* cert, not the root CA cert, even though you inaccurately named it 'chain'.

Basic "how do certificates work" is not really in scope for StackOverflow, but see next door at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/ssl-certificate-framework-101-how-does-the-browser-actually-verify-the-validity .

If you did `openssl s_client -showcerts ... | sed -n '/-BEGIN/,/-END/' >file` that would get *all* the certs *sent*; for *some* servers this includes the root and thus actually is a correct chain -- which would work, because OpenSSL ignores the other cert(s) and uses only the root(s) -- but `www.random.org` does not send its root so that case will not work. If you redacted your example and you actually care about some other server, it may be different and you'll have to check it yourself. (Note that looking in a browser is not reliable; it can and IME always does show you the chain as built and validated, not as sent.)

And to be clear: simply assuming the response you get is actually from the site you named is insecure; it could be an attacker instead, giving you a fake cert *and* chain, and if you trust that chain/root they can steal and/or alter your information and money. For development and experimentation only this can work, but you should never actually use this, and if you don't *also* develop and test, and then use, a secure method of getting the root cert(s) you use, the effort you put into writing code to use SSL/TLS is mostly wasted. (It does still work against passive global scanning, like NSA, GCHQ, and their opposites elsewhere.)

For your case -- Windows -- Microsoft supplies a set of trusted root certs. In fact it supplies *two* for `DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA` which is the one `www.random.org` uses and needs (I'm not sure why two, although they have the same publickey, thus probably either will work, I didn't test). You can see them by running `certmgr.msc`, and export the one(s) you want to a PEM file using right-click, AllTasks, Export. Or you can use powershell. Alternatively, if you don't trust Microsoft (but then why are you using Windows?), the curl project provides a conveniently-downloadable PEM file of the Mozilla (i.e. Firefox and Thunderbird) root-cert store at https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html . Also most Linux distros, including the ones you can run on Windows under WSL, have packaged (thus signed and verified) CA stores, mostly copied from Mozilla like curl's. There are other sources, but this is getting out of scope and really belongs on security.SX as above.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was able to make it work and I understand how this whole thing works better now. Indeed this is probably not a question well suited for stackoverflow since it is not really code related.